# How do I log key-value pairs using NLog's CsvLayout, using the items' keys as columns?

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a system that generates a short list of key-value pairs periodically (`Dictionary<string, string>` basically). The keys are dynamically determined by the application on startup, but after that, they remain consistent over the application lifetime and just the values change. Logically, this information would make sense to store in a CSV layout due to it's simplicity (and makes it easy to plot charts in excel), but I am unsure how best to get NLog to produce this layout.

I know I can't really use the NLog.config because the columns are potentially different, so I've figured out how to add columns at runtime to the layout. I'm not sure how to connect those columns to specific keys in the key-value collection however, and how to provide the collection to NLog programmatically. Does NLog have some sort of type-registration mechanism whereby you can log a specific type in a specific way? I know I can add event properties, but that doesn't seem scalable if I find I need to do something like this again.

Is there some way to register a type-specific handler with NLog?